# Opções de configuração de versão em modo Debug e Release em Delphi

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe3, versionamento

Nos projetos em **Delphi**, temos as opções ***Debug*** e ***Release*** em ***Build Configurations***.

[image: Modos Debug e Release]

Sei que o modo ***Debug*** é utilizado para depurar a aplicação e que gera um executável maior por adicionar pontos de referência para o depurador.
O modo ***Release*** já não inclui os pontos de referência e gera um executável menor, versão essa para ser entregue ao cliente.

Bom, isso é o que eu já sei até o momento.
O que estou precisando saber é se **tem como simplificar as configurações de versão apenas?**

[image: All Configuration]

**Exemplo**: Tem como setar as configurações de versão nas opções em ***All Configurations*** e independete de efetuar o ***build*** na opção ***Debug*** ou ***Release*** eu continuar tendo o mesmo número de versão em ambas?

**Porque isso?** Em desenvolvimento eu faço dez vezes um ***build*** na opção ***Debug*** e com isso, usando a opção de autoincrementar a versão, eu tenho por exemplo uma **versão 1.0.1.10**.
Mas quando vou dar o ***build*** na opção ***Release*** eu tenho o número de **versão 1.0.1.1**.

Logo, preciso ficar mudando, igualando número de versão etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Resposta simples: **Não**.

Resposta não tão simples: Até onde eu sei, não existe forma, da maneira que você está tentando de conseguir o efeito desejado.
Afinal, se você está usando auto increment **na build**, ele é controlado **pela build**, portanto, só incrementa cada vez que você executa a build. Este controle foi adicionado exatamente para isso, termos uma noção de quantas vezes construímos em debug por exemplo, para finalmente chegarmos a um release, e, nem sempre queremos que a versão do cliente seja populada pelos nossos testes.

Mas se realmente te é interessante utilizar um controle só para todas as builds, nem tudo está perdido, [existem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5388750/incrementing-delphi-xe-project-version-number-from-command-line) [formas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2087402/delphi-pre-build-event-not-executing-before-compile) de conseguir controlar a versão como era feito nas versões anteriores. 
Faça uso de um arquivo .bat, e este você pode rodar toda vez que der build, por que não?

---

```bash
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
setLocal EnableDelayedExpansion

SET _myVar=0
FOR /F %%G in (.svn\entries.) DO (
IF !_myVar! LSS 3 SET /A _myVar+=1 & SET _svn_dir_rev=%%G
)

ECHO 1 VERSIONINFO > aVersionInfo.rc
ECHO. FILEVERSION %1,%2,%3,%_svn_dir_rev%   >> aVersionInfo.rc
ECHO. PRODUCTVERSION 1   >> aVersionInfo.rc
ECHO. FILEOS VOS__WINDOWS32   >> aVersionInfo.rc
ECHO. FILETYPE VFT_APP   >> aVersionInfo.rc
ECHO. BEGIN   >> aVersionInfo.rc
ECHO.   BLOCK "StringFileInfo"   >> aVersionInfo.rc
ECHO.   BEGIN   >> aVersionInfo.rc
ECHO.     BLOCK "080904b0"   >> aVersionInfo.rc
ECHO.     BEGIN   >> aVersionInfo.rc
ECHO.       VALUE "CompanyName","COMPANY\000"   >> aVersionInfo.rc
ECHO.       VALUE "FileDescription","APP\000"   >> aVersionInfo.rc
ECHO.       VALUE "FileVersion","%1.%2.%3.%_svn_dir_rev%\000"   >> aVersionInfo.rc
ECHO.       VALUE "InternalName","APP\000"   >> aVersionInfo.rc
ECHO.       VALUE "LegalCopyright","Copyright APP\000"   >> aVersionInfo.rc
ECHO.       VALUE "LegalTrademarks","APP\000"   >> aVersionInfo.rc
ECHO.       VALUE "OriginalFilename","APP.exe\000"   >> aVersionInfo.rc
ECHO.       VALUE "ProductName","APP\000"   >> aVersionInfo.rc
ECHO.       VALUE "ProductVersion,"1\000"   >> aVersionInfo.rc
ECHO.       VALUE "Comments","Compiled on %date% by %username%\000"   >> aVersionInfo.rc
ECHO.     END   >> aVersionInfo.rc
ECHO.   END   >> aVersionInfo.rc
ECHO.   BLOCK "VarFileInfo"   >> aVersionInfo.rc
ECHO.   BEGIN   >> aVersionInfo.rc
ECHO.     VALUE "Translation", 0x0809 1200   >> aVersionInfo.rc
ECHO.   END   >> aVersionInfo.rc
ECHO. END   >> aVersionInfo.rc
ENDLOCAL
```

Comment: O recurso substitui sim o controle de versão do delphi, e onde você está tentando compilar? Deu uma olhada nos threads que eu linkei na resposta?